# express-validator - validate images array

Tags: node.js, express, multer, express-validator

I'm working on a project using Multer to upload an array of images in a field named "images". I need to validate that all images are either PNG or JPG, but I'm having trouble getting the validation to work.

I tried using Express Validator with a custom validation function that checks the file extension, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Express-Validator never gets to an error, even if i upload pdf or xls!

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
  body('images')
  .custom((value, { req }) => {
    const allowedExtensions = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'];
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      const ext = path.extname(value[i].originalname);
      if (!allowedExtensions.includes(ext)) {
        throw new Error(`The file ${value[i].originalname} is not a PNG or JPG file`);
      }
    }

    return true;
  })
  .withMessage('The file must be an image in PNG or JPG format')
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me figure out how to properly validate that all uploaded images are PNG or JPG?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked, what is inside `ext`? Are you sure, that `value` has a length?